# How to get the call stack when my WPF program is crashed

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF program, it crashes sometimes, I want to know the call stack (or some other information) when it crashes. How can I do this?
Great thanks.

================
updated:
Finally, I can log the call stack using below method.
register a handler to log the call stack when an unhandledexception has occurred.

In the main class,
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptions);

If you have other ideas, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the UnhandledException event of the App class

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;
}
private void AppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Log( e.ExceptionObject );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through the code in visual studio?

This should highlight the general area where the code fails.

Moving forward wrapping the affected area in a try...catch statement would allow you to print the contents of the exception and subsequently the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. It is not in the development env, so I cannot use the visual studio to debug. I just want the program can log the call stack on crash.